# Laravel routing, slug with multiple possibilities

Tags: laravel, routes, slug

Been searching for a while and can't find an answer on if this is possible.

One URL I am trying to make. would be

```
/location/province-name/city/category
```

The province name only has a few options. Is there a way to set it up so something like this would work?

```
/{bc or ab or mn or etc}/{cityname}/{category}
```

does this make sense?

Comment: What have you tried? This question could be answered by yourself in seconds to be honest.

Comment: apparently this doesnt make sense. i want to do this, without /locations

wondering if there is a way to have an OR statement inside the slug. but still have them return as a var, so like {BC or AB, or MN  as VAR} which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use a [pattern](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters)

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::pattern('province', '(bc|ab|mn|etc)');

Route::get('/location/{province}/{city}/{category}', function ($province, $city, $category) {
    // TODO do something with your route
});
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! thanks! i figured this was possible somehow. (new to laravel)

Answer (score 1):

```
/{bc or ab or mn or etc}/{cityname}/{category}
```

above approach is more flexible than previous one

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation as,

```
Route::get('/location/{province}/{city}/{category}', function ($province, $city, $category) {

    // show 'Page Not Found' if $province in not in the available options
    if(!in_array($province, ['bc', 'ab','mn'])) {
        abort(404);
    }

    dd($province, $city, $category);
});
```

Comment: It's a way to limit the options for `$province`. Even though you can filter it though patterns while defining a route, the method I suggested will work dynamically.