# laravel redirect route multiple old slugs to the new ones

Tags: php, laravel

My blog urls have changed over the time to more accurate urls.

For example:

1. domain.com/a/1
2. domain.com/b/2
3. domain.com/b/3

But some pages over internet has the old links which I want to redirect in a structured way.

So first I did:

```
Route::get('/a/{slug}', function($slug){
    return redirect('/b/'.$slug, 301);
});
```

Now I have a lot of old slugs and new slugs, and I wonder if there's a smarter way to do, rather than:

```
Route::get('/b/1', function(){
    return redirect('/b/3' 301);
});
Route::get('/b/2', function(){
    return redirect('/b/3' 301);
});
```

I'm looking something like and array or some other better way like:

- old-slug => new-slug
- 1 => 3
- 2 => 3

Or

- (old-slug|old-slug) => new-slug
- (1|2) => 3

I use a laravel package with [this routes](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter/blob/master/src/Routes/web.php)

The closest question I've found [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361948/laravel-routing-slug-with-multiple-possibilities) suggesting something like:

```
Route::pattern('old-slug', '(1|2)');
Route::get('/b/{slug}', function ($old-slug) {
    return redirect('/b/3' 301);
});
```

Questions:

- Is the last solution the way to go?
- If it's, I've tried already and is not working, I might have some error there as I did the code my self based on the other mentioned post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Which one is better?**

Both ways are ok. But if you can cover them using pattern then it will be better because you don't need an extra array. Otherwise, array is more readable and specific because from the array you can get clear idea what `old-sulg` is being replaced by which `new-slug`. Besides, if and one old redirect to one new sulg and another old slug redirect to another new slug then pattern won't be a good choice here. One the other hand, if all old slugs redirect to only one same new slug then patter would be better if possible.

**How to fix the last solution?**

In this solution, you are defining a patters/expression with a name. Like:

`Route::pattern('pattern_name', 'pattern');`

Now, when ever you want to use this pattern, you can just use the `pattern` name. For example:

```
Route::get('url/{pattern_name}', function(){
  // Codes
});
```

here if the url pattern got matched with the define pattern, then the closure will be called.

So, to make your code work, you should refactor it as below:

```
Route::pattern('old_slug', '(1|2)');

Route::get('/b/{old_slug}', function ($oldSlug) {
    return redirect('/b/3' 301);
});
```

Here your pattern name `old-slug` and pattern is `1|2` means `1 or 2`. As  a result, if someone call `/b/1` or `/b/2` it will match the pattern and will execute `return redirect('/b/3' 301);`

Comment: Thank you Imran, so is this the best way to go? because I have a lot of urls, and it would be very convenient for me to have something like.. an array of equivalences (old-slug|old-slug) => new-slug or like pattern old_slug => redirect new_slug, writing it I started about thinking some reemplace

Comment: Answer has been updated. Please have a look at the first section.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally did as it was the easiest and most maintainable way:

```
Route::get('/a/{slug}', function($slug) {

    $urls = [
        '1' => 'b/3',
        '2' => 'b/3'
    ];

    if(isset($urls[$slug])){
        $new_url = $urls[$slug];
    }else{
        $new_url = $b.'/'.$slug;
    };
   return redirect('$new_url, 301);
};
```